# Object enters into another deforming it as it passes through

Tags: animation, physics, surface-deform

I have a cube and I have a sphere.
I would like to do this: the sphere stays fixed at one point and a cube goes up from the bottom.
As the cube goes up it engulfs the sphere and its surface deforms.
The cube continues to rise making the sphere visible again and deforming as the sphere begins to leave the cube.

I have tried many ways to recreate this using physics. I have tried soft body, rigid body and collision, but nothing seems to work.

How could I solve the problem?

Here is a gif to help you understand the movement [image: animation example]

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Hello. How the cube (I presume) is supposed to be deformed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like to create a water deforming effect or a metaball effect, but in this last case I wasn't able to create a metaball cube, I'm only able to make interact metaball spheres

Comment: Have you tried with a Lattice or with a Mesh Deform modifier?

Comment: Can you sketch a few frames showing the desired shape of the sphere and cube as the latter moves through the former?

Comment: @moonboots no, I was trying to create this effect dynamically with physics or metaballs

Comment: As Markus says, some drawings would help

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Sure, added a little storyboard

Comment: Here is the kind of deformation you could have with a Lattice or with a Mesh Deform modifier, why doesn't it fit your needs? https://zupimages.net/up/23/16/z5tt.jpg

Comment: Like this? https://i.imgur.com/W3HssU8.gif

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, exactly, how did you do that?

Comment: You also have the Warp modifier: https://zupimages.net/up/23/16/bpib.jpg

Comment: @moonboots these are definitely functional methods, but I was looking for an "automatic" system so that the deformation would be more realistic. If it is not possible I will try it that way, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. New Project
2. <kbd>H</kbd> Hide the Default Cube
3. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> Add a Metacube.
4. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> Add a Metaball.
5. <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> Move the Metaball above the Metacube.
6. I've set the resolution to $0.05$:

[image]

7. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> Add an empty, you may want to adjust its size for convenience (don't scale it, you don't want the children to be scaled):

[image]

8. Select the Metacube, then <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>-click the empty, so the empty is yellow (active), then <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> parent the Metacube to the empty.
9. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> Reveal the Default Cube, click on it, <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> go to Edit Mode, if it's not selected, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale - make sure it covers the entire MetaCube.
10. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> Go back to Object Mode, with the Default Cube selected, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>-click the empty and again <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> parent the Default Cube to the empty.
11. You're pretty much done, animate the movement of the empty.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, problem solved, thank you very very much! I am a newbie but it really seems like a smart solution, congratulations!